# Preview PDF as image in ranger

Tags: pdf, ranger

How can I preview PDFs as images in [ranger](http://www.nongnu.org/ranger/)? By default it uses `pdftotext` (in the `scope.sh` preview configuration file), but I would like to use [`pdfimages`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfimages), [`pdftoppm`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftoppm), or another graphical solution instead.

The ArchWiki suggests [a method using `pdftoppm`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ranger#PDF_file_preview), but it appears out of date (it does not function as-is, and does not follow the structure of surrounding code).

Comment: Ranger has added this feature since version 1.9.0. See my new answer for details on enabling PDF previews: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445138/191530

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ranger supports this (disabled by default) since v1.9.0 ([see commit `ab8fd9e`](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/pull/995/commits/ab8fd9e8256a1a6c296934af6ffb77bd34671bb2)). To enable this, update your `scope.sh` to the latest version. Note that this will overwrite your previewing configuration file:

```
ranger --copy-config=scope
```

Then find and uncomment the following in `~/.config/ranger/scope.sh`:

```
# application/pdf)
#     pdftoppm -f 1 -l 1 \
#              -scale-to-x 1920 \
#              -scale-to-y -1 \
#              -singlefile \
#              -jpeg -tiffcompression jpeg \
#              -- "${FILE_PATH}" "${IMAGE_CACHE_PATH%.*}" \
#         && exit 6 || exit 1;;
```

Comment: I think you'll also need to comment out the other `pdftotext` configuration in `scope.sh`.

Comment: Worked for me on macos. I did not have to comment out `pdftotext` or modify `scope.sh` in any other way.

Comment: Yep, that's right. The `pdftotext` code will only be used if image previews are disabled.

Answer (score 10):

This works in `ranger-stable 1.8.1`:

```
pdf)
        try pdftoppm -jpeg -singlefile "$path" "${cached//.jpg}" && exit 6 || exit 1;;
```

[image]

I also had to create `~/.cache/ranger` on my system manually.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: That doesn't work for me (ranger 1.8.1 on ubuntu), I had to modified the string substitution a bit to make it work.

try pdftoppm -jpeg -singlefile "$path" "${cached%.*}" && exit 6 || exit 1;;

I guess it is something with shell but I am not an expert on that.

Answer (score 2):

You could try FIM ( http://www.nongnu.org/fbi-improved/#download ). 
It comes with fimgs which allows to view pdf in the console.

On my Arch i had to compile it myself and start it with FBFONT set to "fim://".

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code this way to make it work:

```
pdftoppm -jpeg -singlefile "$path" "$cached" && mv "$cached.jpg" "$cached" && exit 6 || exit 1;;
```

Comment: Please post this as a comment on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408276/191530 and clarify what change you made and why.